# Prevent toast Message from getting cancelled on touch

Tags: android, touch-event, android-toast

I am developing a game in which I am displaying toast messages for instructions.

The problem is as soon as the user touches the screen, toast message is getting cancelled.

How can I prevent onTouch event from cancelling toast message?

Code used to create toast message:

```
    Toast.makeText(context, toastMsg, toastLength);
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Why do you think that using a `Toast` for instructions is a good idea in the first place?

Comment: Do you call `show()` on the `Toast` message?  It won't pop up if you don't.

Comment: Not that I would ever recommend it, but you could sleep your thread for the length of your toast so that it isn't "active". Again, would never recommend sleeping the thread it is just a super hacked (possible) answer.

Comment: You could make a small information box in the UI to give info to the user. Better for the user

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have more upvotes for this question. I was about to ask the same thing as a search of this didn't get a relevant result. I would think this would be a huge issue for game developers, it was for me.

Comment: Just don't use toasts for this.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `transparent` `dialog` with a timer that i often use in my helper `class` to give guide or instructions.

```
public static void Toaster(final Context ctx, final String text) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
            android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.guide);
    TextView guide = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.g_text);
    guide.setText(text);
    Button buy = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gotit);
    buy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

and here is the `xml` file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"        
        android:id="@+id/g_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#2f72da"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/got_it" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and simply call it by using

```
Toaster(YourClassName.this,"Your Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use alert buttons

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Warning");
            builder.setMessage("this is a question?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     //do sth

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do sth else
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a game developer, so this is a big issue for me. Toasts not only disappear on screen taps, but are also vulnerable to screen drags. OpenGL offers no text support, so without toasts I ended up having to create and display a bitmap of any temporary text I wanted to show. This was hugely time and memory consuming, particularly for multiple language support.

My hack is to use a global variable for the toast string, set a Long variable to the System time it intitially launched, and then reshow the toast in my downtouch interface code if any downtouch happens before 3500 milliseconds (duration Toast.LENGTH_LONG) has passed.

```
for (int downtouch = 0; downtouch < downTouches.length; downtouch++) {
  ...
   if(downtouch==0&&System.currentTimeMillis()<toastmessagestart+3500) {//the first of any simultaneous touches
            ((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                Toast toast;
                public void run() {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()<toastmessagestart+1500){//duration Toast.LENGTH_LONG - duration Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), globaltoaststring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else{
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), globaltoaststring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
   }
```

This hack isn't perfect, as the perceived length of the toast will vary a bit depending on screen interaction, but it will be at least 3500 milliseconds. Also there may be intermittent fading, but surprisingly not much.

Comment: If your game means any value, you probably want some in-app UI for this stuff rather than toasts.